# Does a function exist that searches the unix $PATH variable and returns true if a certain file exists?

Tags: c, linux, unix

The execvp() function executes the program that is given as an argument. It checks the $PATH variable to find the program. I'm writing something in which I would like to check to see if several programs exist before calling any exec() functions. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You should probably not just rely on existence - you need the file to have execute permissions (for you) too.  Even that's not foolproof; if the program starts #!/bin/non-existent, it won't execute because the program does not exist.  That's why execlp() just tries each name in turn, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

You can use getenv to get the PATH environment variable and then search through it.

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getenv.html

You can then use fopen to check for the existence of the specific binary names.

You can also do something like system("which App"). which searches $PATH for you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_(C_standard_library)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_(Unix)

Answer (score 3):

glibc's and netbsd's execvp actually tries to exec the command for every element along the path until it succeeds or runs out of path to search.  Doesn't leave a lot of room for reuse, but seems good.

In general, for questions like this, I like to go to the source and see what it does.  NetBSD's is generally the best read:

- [NetBSD execvp source](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/gen/execvp.c?rev=1.30&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN)
- [glibc execvp source](http://sources.redhat.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/libc/posix/execvp.c?rev=1.27&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=glibc)

Comment: The code is actually on execvp, not execlp (the NetBSD link was already pointing to execvp); I edited your answer to be what you probably intended (feel free to revert if I got it wrong).

Answer (score 2):

the command **which** probably is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an absolute (canonicalized) pathname, you can use either **stat**(2) or **access**(2) to see if the file exists.

With stat:

```
struct stat st;
if (stat(path, &st)) {
   // path doesn't exist
}
```

With access:

```
if (access(path, F_OK)) {
   // path doesn't exist
}
```